# Looking for dataframe.apply() without shape restrictions

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to do Spline interpolations separately on each column of a smaller dataframe timeseries to create a finer resolved dataframe time-series with a larger dimension than the original.

So, ideally the code would look similar to this (in pseudo-code):

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline as Spline
import pandas as pd

few_times = pd.date_range(t0, t1, periods=10)
few_times_for_spline = few_times.values.astype('float')
many_times = pd.date_range(t0, t1, periods=1000)
many_times_for_spline = many_times.values.astype('float')

df_to_interp = pd.DataFrame(randn(10,100), index=few_times)

def do_spline(col):
    return Spline(few_times_for_spline, col)(many_times_for_spline)

df_to_interp.apply(do_spline)
```

But this gives me errors, because the dimensions are not coerce-able to the original dataframe dimensions. I am a bit puzzled why it is not working, because the df.groupby().apply() allows to change dimensions of the returned values.

My solution so far is going down to pure numpy and use its function `apply_along_axis`:

```
pd.DataFrame(apply_along_axis(do_spline, 
                              0, 
                              df_to_interp.values), 
             index=many_times, 
             columns=df_to_interp.columns)
```

but I was wondering if there is not a more `panda-esque` solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of .13, you should be able to use `reindex` and `interpolate` to do this (as long as you have `scipy`).

```
In [54]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4).cumsum(0)
, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2010-01-01', freq='s', periods=100))

In [55]: many_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='ms')

In [56]: df.index
Out[56]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2010-01-01 00:01:39]
Length: 100, Freq: S, Timezone: None

In [57]: many_idx
Out[57]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2010-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2010-01-01 00:01:39]
Length: 99001, Freq: L, Timezone: None
```

So now the idea is to `reindex` `df` to `many_idx` and fill in the resulting `NaN`s with a spline (separately  for each column). There seems to be a bug somewhere in pandas/scipy where just doing `df.reindex(many_idx).interpolate(method='spline', order=1)` complains about not being able to cast the index dtype from `dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64')`, so as a workaround:

```
In [61]: df.reindex(many_idx).reset_index().interpolate(method='spline', order=1).set_index('index')
Out[61]: 
                                   0         1         2         3
index                                                             
2010-01-01 00:00:00        -0.623775  0.069668 -0.010604 -0.201834
2010-01-01 00:00:00.001000 -0.621875  0.569733  0.081842 -0.278664
2010-01-01 00:00:00.002000 -0.621800  0.570461  0.081998 -0.278531
2010-01-01 00:00:00.003000 -0.621725  0.571190  0.082153 -0.278397
2010-01-01 00:00:00.004000 -0.621651  0.571918  0.082308 -0.278263
2010-01-01 00:00:00.005000 -0.621576  0.572647  0.082463 -0.278130
2010-01-01 00:00:00.006000 -0.621502  0.573376  0.082618 -0.277996
2010-01-01 00:00:00.007000 -0.621427  0.574104  0.082774 -0.277862
2010-01-01 00:00:00.008000 -0.621352  0.574833  0.082929 -0.277729
2010-01-01 00:00:00.009000 -0.621278  0.575561  0.083084 -0.277595
2010-01-01 00:00:00.010000 -0.621203  0.576290  0.083239 -0.277462
2010-01-01 00:00:00.011000 -0.621128  0.577018  0.083395 -0.277328
```

Does that look like what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you maybe have insight why the groupby().apply() allows different dimensions to be returned, while the DataFrame.apply() does not?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I think `DataFrame.apply` needs a function that either reduces or returns a 1-d result. `Groupby.apply` is a bit more flexible about what gets returned.